# Hosting server farm begind VPN

Tags: apache, vpn

I have a set up I would like to implement but just not sure on the details. As you can see in the image below I have a single VPS in the web which I would like to use as a gateway to a number of locally running web servers. Im using the VPN to hide the IP/location of the server farm while maintaining the ability to host locally.

What I am not sure on is the implementation as I have never used a VPN before. My understanding is that I can host the VPN server on the server farm, have the VPS connect to it which will give me another 'local' network interface which I can then use apache to proxy traffic through?

The server farm is basically a small Kubernetes cluster give or take a little.

Is my understanding correct and can you offer any advice on implementaion?

Thanks in advance!

[server farm example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzfhw.png)

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

The VPN server should have two network interfaces. The first is the public interface that connects to the Internet and the second is the local interface that connects to the server farm. All the servers in the farm should connect only to the local interface and have the gateway set as the VPN server.

You can use the Reverse Proxy functionality in Apache to route incoming traffic to the appropriate server. See [Reverse Proxy Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)